# Express static files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

When I visit 'http://localhost:8787/article_detail/41',the css and js files all can not be loaded,but when the url is 'http://localhost:8787/about',all the files were loaded correctly,Why?

### app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//read cookies
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'chenzimu'}));
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/admin',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//template engine 
app.engine("html", hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine','html');
//route
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/admin/api', admin);
```

### html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/html5shiv.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below it will work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/html5shiv.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is because if you add any path params or any extra paths from the base path then server looks up the page related css or scripts form the different location.